# Which modules are guaranteed to be present in Blender's Python?

Tags: python

Which modules are guaranteed to be included in Blender's custom Python build?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Everything included in the Python standard library, except the modules `tkinter`, `turtledemo`, `distutils`, `idlelib`, `lib2to3` and `test`.

Here's the [rationale for why these modules were not included](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2008-December/022295.html).

Comment: Running `help('modules')` could also prove useful..

Comment: Check: http://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/source/creator/CMakeLists.txt - line 450, shows the data thats excluded.

Answer (score 7):

Run from console to find out.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

anything located in any of these directories. the standard python library stuff will be located in `...\\x.xx\\python\\lib`, where `x.xx` is the release version, currently 2.67.